# Django form not displaying date widget

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm having a hard time getting a date widget to appear in django. Keeping in mind that the project is meant to have zero access to the internet, this is what I have:

forms.py:

```
class CreateNewPatient(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.PatientInfo
    fields = ['first_name', 'nickname','last_name',
        'date_of_birth', 'school_grade', 'sex', 'school']
    widgets = {
        'date_of_birth' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
    }
```

template with form:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

{% block content %}

<!--Form Container-->
<div class="container">
  <form  action="{% url 'patientRecords:new_patient' %}" method="post" 
class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The form is being generated using a bootstrap 4 plugin. That't why there is some weird syntax to generate the form.

javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      changeDay: true,
      yearRange: "1990:2030",
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have the javascript placed in the head tag of the base layout template. The .datepicker class tag shows up correctly in the source code on chrome, but no form is generated. I still just get a text box for entering a date. How can I make the form display using a widget here?

Answer (score 2):

You're loading bootstarp_js in your form template, but calling the `$(".datepicker").datepicker()` function in head tag. So, its trying to call datepicker function before loading your bootstrap_js.Which is why its not showing up (looking at your browser console errors, should help you)

So you should include your bootstrap_js file before datepicker function in Head tag or call datepicker function in form template after `{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}`

Comment: I tried placing the javascript right before the endblock tag in the form template and it still did not function.

Comment: Did you see any errors in Chrome developer console?

Comment: I got 2 warnings. one was "runtime.onMessageExternal is not supported" and the other was "runtime.onConnectExternal is not supported". both errors are at "content.bundle.js:5"

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery-UI library for datepicker, are you including jquery-ui.js file? (https://jqueryui.com/download/)

Comment: I was not. I will try including this. Thanks!